# How do i design database and get data by Category in android

Tags: android, sql, database, cursor

For example data  if i categorize data to 3 group : Attraction, City landmark, Park

```
id      title           content          address           category

1     GeneralPark     xxxxxxxxxxx      1234road         Park

2     GreatMuseum      wwwwwwwwww       9877road         Attraction
```

Look at General Park. its category is Park. and it also in Attraction category. the question is .. how can i design database? Is it possible to  do like the following(put Park and Attraction in the same column):

```
id      title           content          address           category

1     GeneralPark     xxxxxxxxxxx      1234road         Park,Attraction
```

So, if it's not, then how can i design database? and How should i implement this line to retrive data by category; i.e. By Attraction

```
public Cursor getplaces() 
{
    Cursor c = mDb.query(Constants.TABLE_NAME_PLACE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    return c;

}
```

The expect result should show only Attraction Category:

```
id      title           content          address           category

1     GeneralPark     xxxxxxxxxxx      1234road          Attraction

2     GreatMuseum      wwwwwwwwww       9877road         Attraction

4     Middlehigh-school ttttttttt       555road           Attraction

5     ShoppingMall   ssssssssss        666road           Attraction
```

Thanks so much for your help. i'm quite new to developing. Thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put two things (i.e. 'Park,Attraction') in one column, that is almost always a mistake. The usual way to deal with this situation is to add another table with two columns:

```
create table place_categories (
    place_id int          not null references place(id),
    category varchar(255) not null,
    primary key (place_id, category)
)
```

You'd usually make a two column primary key to avoid duplicates as well, hence the `primary key` constraint at the bottom. A [foreign key](http://www.sqlite.org/syntaxdiagrams.html#foreign-key-clause) on `place_id` would be a good idea too, referential integrity saves a lot of pain, suffering, and confusion.

And then, if you want to work with the categories for a place, just join to `place_categories`:

```
select p.id
from place p
join place_categories c on (p.id = c.place_id)
where c.category = 'Attraction'
```

With this approach, your `place` table would look something like this:

```
create table place (
    id      int          not null primary key,
    title   varchar(100) not null,
    content varchar(100) not null,
    address varchar(100) not null
)
```

and the data would look something like this:

```
id      title           content          address
1     GeneralPark      xxxxxxxxxxx      1234road
2     GreatMuseum       wwwwwwwwww      9877road
```

Comment: Is that mean.. In Place Table i need to have data like this:
1     GeneralPark     xxxxxxxxxxx      1234road      Park//2     GeneralPark     xxxxxxxxxxx      1234road      Attraction------2 row that have the same data, different only id and category?

Comment: @April: The `place` table would only have `id`, `title`, `content,` and `address` columns, all the category information goes in `place_categories`. See my update for some clarification.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, first things first, learn about relational databases, and normalization. It may be a trivial thing for you, but it's not. Maybe someone can give you the code to solve this, but you won't learn anything from that.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relational_database

Then, you'll read some SQL to access files in a smart way.
example of SQL> "SELECT DATE, NAME, ADDRESS FROM People WHERE NAME='Jane'"

Comment: yep, i see.. i need to learn more about this. 
the one reason, i have to ask someone to solve this because tomorrow is my deadline date. I have to submit the progress 1 to professor. i just need to have something to submit and after that i do have time to learn. anyway, thanks for your help.

Comment: Don't give up so fast, the task you need to solve is easy, some skimming might get you done.